# External scripts/css in hybrid android apps

Tags: android, cordova, apk, hybrid-mobile-app

The [Android best practices documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html) states

> Because mobile devices typically have a connection speed far slower than a desktop computer, you should make your web pages load as fast as possible. One way to speed it up is to avoid loading extra files such as stylesheets and script files in the . Instead, provide your CSS and JavaScript directly in the  (or at the end of the , for scripts that you don't need until the page is loaded). Alternatively, you should optimize the size and speed of your files by compressing them with tools like Minify.

I have not done much mobile development of late but I was under the impression - recall having read - that hybrid apps that are "incomplete" because they rely on CSS and/or JS that has to be fetched from an external source are in general not a good idea.  Though this question is about Android I have also had the impression that on the iOS an app submission may be rejected if it is found to have such dependencies.

Either I am wrong on both fronts or else the *best practices* documentation does not reflect the way developers work in the real world.  I'd much appreciate feedback here on the *do's* and *don'ts* when it comes to sticking in `&lt;link&gt;` and `&lt;script&gt;` tags in hybrid phone - specifically Android - apps.

Comment: if you use cordova for development, the js and css should be local to the app. Using an external source is possible, but never a good idea

Comment: I agree with jcesarmobile